# Cannot reading property 'GetTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts, undefined

I am using canvasJS to graph data. I make an AJAX request and get a list of data that can be graphed in this format:

```
 dataPoints: [{
     x: new Date(2012, 00, 1),
     y: 450
 }, {
     x: new Date(2012, 01, 1),
     y: 414
 }, ]
```

My list that I get back from the AJAX request looks like:

```
sup_2 = [{ x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },{ x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414 },]
```

I cannot seem to pass it in as a variable to use, even though it is formatted correctly. To clarify, if I copy what sup_2 is and paste it in, I will see a graph, but when I leave as is below, I get the above error and I see nothing.

My function looks like this:

```
<script>
function sample_current(sup_2) {
    console.log(sup_2)
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("temperatureChart", {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        toolTip: {
            shared: "true" //disable here. 
        },
        title: {
            text: "Sample Temp",
            fontSize: 18
        },
        axisX: {
            title: "time",
            gridThickness: .2,
            lineThickness: .2,
            titleFontSize: 14,
            labelFontSize: 12,
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Temperature (C)",
            gridThickness: .2,
            lineThickness: .2,
            titleFontSize: 14,
            labelFontSize: 12,

        },
        data: [{
            markerType: "triangle",
            type: "line",
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            showInLegend: true,
            name: "Supply",
            dataPoints: sup_2
        }, ],
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>

<script>
function get_temp_data(element_id, period){
        $("#temperatureChart").foggy();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/sample/test_function",
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        data:{},
        success: function(data) {
            sample_current(data.b)            
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('choose the facility');
        }
      });        
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that one of your dates isn't real? `new Date(2012, 00, 1)` The 0th month of the year?

Comment: @SamuelDavidson Nope, check out this link: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-line-chart/

Comment: @SamuelDavidson I'm pretty sure months are 0 based in Javascript... 0 Being January. You'd be correct for other languages though, month 0 generally isn't a thing.

Comment: @SamuelDavidson If I copy what sup_2 is and paste it in instead of the variable, I can see a graph, but when I write in the variable sup_2, I get nothing

Comment: That is interesting. Anyways could you try debugging in Chrome or something and ensuring your `sup_2` object is correctly filled out at run-time?

Comment: When and where is `sample_current` called?

Comment: @Ishettyl I updated the post accordingly